# Unable to access System defined environment variables in the apache module source code

Tags: java, c, apache, environment-variables, apache-modules

In general scenario, while coding in java, we use System.getProperty("users.home") in order to get the users home directory.

Similarly, when i was trying to develop a module for apache web server(in c language) in Windows7, i am unable to find any way of using the environment variables into the apache module.

My problem is I want to get the users home directory into the apache module source code. Please let me know any possible way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[`getenv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx) is the method of choice for this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

const char v[] = "HOMEPATH";
char * p = getenv(v);
printf("%s = '%s'\n", v, p ?p :"<no set>");
```

Comment: hai alk,thanks for your reply. The above code works fine in case of normal c program, but when coming to the apache module source code, there is no function which is able to retrieve the environment variable and resulting in the output as <no set> in the apache module source code. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: @user_3093890: `getenv()` should be part of the C Standard Library, at least on those platforms where Apache builds. Make sure to `#include` `<stdlib.h>`. Which platform are you on? Which error message do you receive?